# int key starting at specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 code first. I have the following model:

```
public class Book {
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Title {get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

How do I set the auto-incrementing ID property to start at 100 (or any other value) instead of 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this elegantly in EF AFAIK.

You could either create the table in SQL manually:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(
    BookID INT IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL, 
    --
```

Or I guess you could execute a `DBCC CHECKIDENT` once the table is created by EF, viz:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(Book,RESEED,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto-increment identity does not have to do with EF. In SSMS use;

DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, Seed_Start)

Or Truncating the table also produces same result